# Stored procedure get parameter list and current values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Not sure how to implement this, but I need a way to get the current list of parameters for a stored procedure as well as their passed in values (this code will be executed in the stored procedure itself).

I know I can use `sys.parameters` to get the parameter names, but how to get the actual values?

What I need to do with this is to make a char string of the form

```
@param_name1=@value1,@param_name2=@value2,...,@param_namen=@valuen
```

I have tried to use dynamic sql, but not having much joy with that.

Any ideas??

Edit:

Currently I am just going through all the parameters one-by-one to build the string. However I want a "better" way to do it, since there are quite a few parameters. And incase parameters are added later on (but the code to generate the string is not updated).

I tried using dynamic sql but gave up, since the `sp_executesql` sp requires parameters be passed into it...

Comment: Interesting but weird requirement. Could you please show us what you tried?

Comment: Not so weird if you want to log full error data from catch blocks in stored procedures, [I use something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674216/1062992).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state '(this code will be executed in the stored procedure itself).' so assuming you are in the procedure you will already know the parameter names as you have to declare them when creating your procedure. Just do a select and put the names inside text fields

```
ALTER PROCEDURE procname
(
     @param1 NVARCHAR(255)
    ,@param2 INT
    ...
)

SELECT [Parameters] = '@param1=' + @param1 
                    + ',@param2=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@param2)...
```

The `CONVERT` is there as an example for non-char datatypes.

---

### update

You will need to create a linked server that points to itself to use the `OPENQUERY` function.

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [.]    Script Date: 04/03/2013 16:22:13 ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'.', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'.', @provstr=N'Integrated Security=SSPI'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'.',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

GO
```

Now you can do something like this cursor to get each parameter name and then use dynamic sql in `OPENQUERY` to get the value:

```
DECLARE curParms CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    name
FROM sys.parameters
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('schema.procedurename')
ORDER BY parameter_id
OPEN curParms
FETCH curParms INTO @parmName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    SELECT @parmName + '=' + (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('linkedservername','SELECT ' + @parmName))
    FETCH curParms INTO @parmName
END
CLOSE curParms
DEALLOCATE curParms
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add something, I am already using that method of manually going through the parameters. But the sp has quite a lot of parameters, and so I wanted a less painful way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL Server 2014 we have `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer`, it is a table valued function with an output column `event_info` that gives the full execution statement (including parameters).

We can parse the param values from `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` and get the param names from `sys.parameters` and join them together to get the string you want.

For example:

```
create procedure [dbo].[get_proc_params_demo]
(
    @number1 int,
    @string1 varchar(50),
    @calendar datetime,
    @number2 int,
    @string2 nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin

-- get the full execution statement
declare @statement nvarchar(max)
select  @statement = event_info
from    sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@spid, current_request_id())

-- parse param values from the statement
declare @proc_name varchar(128) = object_name(@@procid)
declare @param_idx int = charindex(@proc_name, @statement) + len(@proc_name)
declare @param_len int = len(@statement) - @param_idx 
declare @params nvarchar(max) = right(@statement, @param_len)

-- create param values table
select  value, row_number() over (order by current_timestamp) seq
into    #params
from    string_split(@params, ',')

-- get final string
declare @final nvarchar(max)
select  @final = isnull(@final + ',','') + p1.name + '=' + ltrim(p2.value)
from    sys.parameters p1
        left join #params p2 on p2.seq = parameter_id
where   object_id = @@procid

select  @final params
end
```

To test it:

```
exec get_proc_params_demo 42, 'is the answer', '2019-06-19', 123456789, 'another string'
```

Returns the string you want:

```
@number1=42,@string1='is the answer',@calendar='2019-06-19',@number2=123456789,@string2='another string'
```

I have something similar wrapped as a UDF. I use it for error logging in catch blocks.