# Log value of store procedures parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How can log value of stored procedures parameters in sql server?  (something like sql profiler which shows parameters and their values)

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: @Dan Guzman , SQL Server 2016

Comment: If you're able to modify the proc, you can just add an `INSERT` that saves the values into a table before the store proc does any of its operations.

Comment: Looks like this question over on dbaexchange may be what you're looking for: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/tracking-down-a-stored-procedures-parameters-after-execution

Comment: It might be useful.Im using "egerardus" answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201901/stored-procedure-get-parameter-list-and-current-values